# How to setup specific call to for mocks?

Tags: c#, mocking, fakeiteasy

I'm using FakeItEasy to mock stuff within unit tests but somehow i fail to setup
pretty basic scenario. ie. i want to throw exception when specific user accesses a method. Help would be nice... thanks

```
A.CallTo(() => m_fancyRepository
                .CanIDoFancyThings(A<User>
                    .That
                    .Matches(u => u.Id.Equals(m_user.Id)))
                .Verify())
                .Throws(new Exception("omg !!! ???!"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `Verify()` method after the stub, like this:

```
A.CallTo(() => m_fancyRepository.CanIDoFancyThings(
            A<User>.That.Matches(u => u.Id.Equals(m_user.Id))))
            .Throws(new Exception("omg !!! ???!"));
```

Comment: Great job thanks, Verify() is method of CanIDoFancyThings() returns.

Comment: @eugeneK Hum, I'm  never used _FakeItEasy_, so I was thinking it have the `Verify` method like in _Moq_, :+1:. Is it not the correct answer?XD

Comment: @ Joel Ramos Michaliszen then answer is right because this is what i missed in code. A.CallTo is like Verify in moq.